# How show only sum of the labels for a stacked bar chart using jqplot?

Tags: java, jqplot

Here I need to show only sum of the bars at the top, not needed the label on each stacked bar.
How can I remove  the labels on each bar? ....When I have used the code   pointLabels: {show: false} it removed all the labels, but i need the sum at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added pointLabels for each series and put show:false for each series except the last one.

```
seriesDefaults: {
          renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
          rendererOptions:{barMargin: 25}, 

          pointLabels:{show:false,                  
                       stackedValue: true}
      },
        series:[
            {
        pointLabels:{show:false,                  
                       stackedValue: false}
      },
            {
        pointLabels:{show:false,                  
                       stackedValue: false}
      },
            {
        pointLabels:{show:true,      

                       stackedValue: false}
  },
        ]
```